# HTML Form Submit button doesn't work, only reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I wanted to make a settings page for a Chrome Extension, but the save button doesn't work.  The .click() doesn't even activate at all.  I put all of my code beneath.  Also, do I use the commented out button instead(see below)?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Y.A.Y | Options</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/caps.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <form>

            <label>Enabled: </label>
            <select id="on">
                <option value="on">Yes</option>
                <option value="off">No</option>
            </select>

            </br>

            <label>First Letter:</label>
            <select id="first">
                <option value="on">Capital</option>
                <option value="off">Lowercase</option>
            </select>

            </br>

            <label>Change First Letter of Each </label>
            <select id="per">
                <option value="on">Word</option>
                <option value="off">Sentence</option>
            </select>
            <!--<input id="save" type = "submit" value = "Save"/>!-->
            <button id="yayay" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var pretty_fied = false;

var isOn;
var isCapFirst;
var firstLetterPerWord;

getData()

function getData() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(function (data) {
        isOn = data.isOn;
        isCapFirst = data.isCapFirst;
        firstLetterPerWord = data.firstLetterPerWord;
    })
}

$('form').on('submit', function () {
    alert("HI!");
    isOn = ($("#on").value == "on");
    isCapFirst = ($("#first").value == "on");
    firstLetterPerWord = ($("#per").value == "on");
    console.log(isOn);
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        isOn: isOn,
        isCapFirst: isCapFirst,
        firstLetterPerWord: firstLetterPerWord
    });
    console.log("Saved");
});
```

Comment: add action in form either it is some other page or controller or function name which perform action on this data

Answer (score 0):

In the form field you should specify the action, in other words what you are doing with the form
Eg.

```
    <form action ='test.php' method="post"></form>

Which will send the form to a file called test.php

In the case though you will want to use jquery submit.

This is an example using the submit function in jquery:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp

notice that the action part is left blank, because you do not wish to send a request to another document.

Comment: But I don't use PHP?